# css is not loaded in the jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery plugin for flat radio button with three choices from the following link: http://jqueryui.com/button/#radio

and it is working if use directly with html code but it is not working if i use same code using

```
$("#id").append("html code for radio button").
```

when I inspecting on browser using inspect element then found that html code of radio button generated with jquery  is different from other one. however I have written it same. After loading it changes. Dont why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.buttonset()` after append;

```
$("#id").append('<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio">').buttonset();
```

Here is working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJqBF/1/)**